# how to change the src of an image when clicking and it return to the original after some time?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, src

I have a page that displays several hidden divs when clicking on image-buttons (next and previous). sometimes takes a few seconds for its content to show up correctly, so I had the idea of ​​delaying the functions a bit to "give time" for the content to "prepare". While that time the image exchanges for a gif.
I already started and saw that it works, I got a simple way with `tris.src` to change the `img` and `setInterval` for the delay, direct on my `onclick=""`, but I need the original image to automatically return to the original after 2 or 3 seconds because it can showed again (when clicked on previous button) and should not to be a gif anymore! and don't know how to do this. can you help me?

CSS:

## div1, #div2 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: yellow;position: relative;

## next {position: absolute bottom: 20px; left: 20px}

}
HTML & JS:

```
<div id="div1">
    content1
    <img src="next.png" id="next" onclick="setTimeout(replace, 1000); this.src='prev.png'">
    <input type="hidden" value="prev.png" id="hdnPreviousPng" />
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none">content2
    <img src="next.png" id="next" onclick="setTimeout(replace2, 1000); this.src='prev.png'">
    <input type="hidden" value="prev.png" id="hdnPreviousPng" />
</div>

<script>
    function replace() { 
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block";
        setInterval(function(){
             let originalSrc = $('#hdnPreviousPng').val();
             $('#next').attr('src', originalSrc);

        }, 3000); 
    }
    function replace2() { 
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block";
        setInterval(function(){
             let originalSrc = $('#hdnPreviousPng').val();
             $('#next').attr('src', originalSrc);
    
        }, 3000); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You could create input elements with type hidden and store the original src value in the value property of your hidden elements, then give your hidden element(s) some id or class that relates them to their respective img, then in setInterval() grab the value of the hidden element(s) and use that to reset your img src

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: @RyanWilson I could not understand....

Comment: @Adam Azad, posted!

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra I'll post an example of what I mean as an answer.

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra I would consider using setTimeout() instead of setInterval() since you only need this to fire off once and to return the attribute src back to its original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a simple data attribute to store some state and swap in and out image source tags.

Here is an example of how this would work using JavaScript:

```js
function clicked() {
  replace();
  setTimeout(replace, 1000);
}

function replace() {
  var next = document.getElementById("next").getAttribute("data-img-src");
  var current = document.getElementById("next").src;

  document.getElementById("next").setAttribute("data-img-src", current);
  document.getElementById("next").src = next;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img id="next" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=first" data-img-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=second" onclick="clicked();">
</div>
```

If you need to account for multiple clicks and still return to the original image you will need some more state and can try this:

```js
function clicked() {
  replace();
  setTimeout(replaceOriginal, 1000);
}

function replace() {
  var next = document.getElementById("next").getAttribute("data-img-src");

  document.getElementById("next").src = next;
}

function replaceOriginal(){
  var original = document.getElementById("next").getAttribute("data-img-original");

  document.getElementById("next").src = original;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img id="next" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=first" data-img-original="http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=first" data-img-src="http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=second" onclick="clicked();">
</div>
```